# Better way to get Microsoft Failover Cluster IP address resource through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

Is there a better way to view the IP address assigned to cluster IP address resource through PowerShell?

Today, I use `Get-ClusterResource`, but I have to populate the cluster IP address resource name field with the IP address. That seems weird to me, but it works.

Here is how I get the IP addresses now:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ClusterResource

Name                    State  OwnerGroup    ResourceType
----                    -----  ----------    ------------
Cluster Name            Online Cluster Group Network Name
IP Address 10.10.10.x Online SRXSVC        IP Address
IP Address 10.10.10.y Online Cluster Group IP Address
IP Address 10.20.70.z Online SRXSVC        IP Address
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. You ask for a "better way". Can you show us the code you currently use? Without knowing that, it's hard to propose something "better".

Comment: I use "Get-ClusterResource | SLS 'IP Address'" and get list of IP address that I parse. I put example in original question.

Answer (score 3):

This will be a little bit cleaner. It'll return just the IP address.

```
get-clusterresource -name "cluster ip address" | get-clusterparameter -name Address | select -Property Value
```

Returns:

```
Value
-----
172.16.100.204
```

Comment: I get an error when I run the command. get-clusterresource : An error occurred opening resource 'cluster ip address'.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-clusterresource -name "cluster ip address" | get-clusterparameter ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-ClusterResource], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.GetResourceCommand

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way to retrieve the cluster IP address without using explicit names:

```
Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object { $_.GroupType -eq "Cluster" } |
    Get-ClusterResource | Where-Object { $_.ResourceType -eq "IP Address" } |
    Get-ClusterParameter -Name "Address" | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to return the IP address(es):

```
Get-ClusterResource | Where { $_.ResourceType -eq "IP Address" } | Get-ClusterParameter -Name "Address" | Select ClusterObject, Value
```